# Rails Memcached Usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, memcached

I'm looking into using memcached for my rails application.  I was considering using it on my member search, but I am confused because there are multiple parameters for the search which will be changing through user selection.

This is an example of a query for the search:

```
 @results = Painter.city(params[:city].downcase).state(params[:state]).tools(tools).transportation(trans).travel_distance(params[:travel_distance]).insurance(insurance).employee(emp).subcontractor(sub).available(true).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20).where("premium = ? AND banned = ?", false, false).order('last_name')
```

This seems like a likely candidate for memcached, but I am unsure.

Please provide direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could certainly cache this using Memcached. You must start by deciding on a format for your **cache keys**, and when you have several different criteria/fields that uniquely determine a cache record (such as in your case) you can probably just concatenate them in a pre-determined order, using some kind of string to separate them. For instance, your cache key may look like this:

```
@results = Rails.cache.fetch([params[:city].downcase,
                   params[:state],
                   tools,
                   trans,
                   params[:travel_distance],
                   insurance,
                   emp,
                   sub,
                   params[:page]
                  ].join('/')) do
  Painter.city(params[:city].downcase)...  # rest of your query
end
```

You may want to tweak or clean up the format, but the gist of it is that you must be able to calculate a *consistent* cache key as a String. The easiest way to do that for multiple fields is to `join` them using a separator (I chose `/`, but you can use other separators if you choose.)

Note also that I left out the `:per_page => 20`, since that is hard-coded within your controller code and will not vary based on user input. If you decide to allow users to customize how many records are returned, you would need to include that in the cache key as well. Same goes for the `where("premium = ? AND banned = ?", false, false)` clause, and `available(true)`.

You can use Rails caching for any kind of content that is non-trivial to look up from its original source (i.e., if it involves DB queries).

Of course a very important consideration to keep in mind is **cache expiration**: if/when you add new records to your DB that match the criteria of data you have in your cache, you must be sure to **expire** the data in your cache manually, or else set an automatic expiration when you `write` to the cache so that it will eventually be purged and refreshed on its own.

Using Memcached in Rails, manual expiration of the cache involves a `delete`:

```
Rails.cache.delete(key)
```

Or to use automatic expiration, use the `:expires_in` option:

```
Rails.cache.write(key, value, :expires_in => 1.minute)
```

Comment: This makes sense thank you. If you have a minute can your provide some examples of when to cache and when not to?  For example, my user's have profiles.  Would caching a user's profile using a fragment be another likely candidate?  It's all about increasing performance right?

Comment: Also, in the above code how would I add the result of the query to the cache based on the key?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include some more details, including cache expiration which is very important

Comment: My example snippet above sets the cache value to your `@results` instance variable, meaning the cache will hold the value of the array of results

Comment: Also don't miss the [Rails Guide to Caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html) if you haven't seen it

Comment: Alright cool, wont the query still execute each time then? Seems I would run the query then store the results?

Comment: Oh duh, I forgot to use `fetch(key) do ... end` instead of `write` :) `fetch` skips running the "expensive" code in the block if it finds the key first (I'm getting tired :) Updated my answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28233/discussion-between-brian-and-stuart-m)